# python timestamp and unix dates

Tags: python, timestamp, timedelta

I have the following query, getting some data, I need to select those which have been added yesterday only, excluding today. I am struggling to incorporate it in the script.

In my data I have 'created date' which is unix format

```
docs_all = db.collection('collection').where('created','>','1675863274685').stream()
for doc in docs_all:
    print(doc.to_dict())
```

I dont know if it is better to convert unix to date or the other way round and how to add date = current_date - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to get an appropriate strings to put into `where` close to filter only yesterday.

I suggest calculating today - 1 as date (without hours and minutes), then creating a datetime corresponding to the start of yesterday (00:00:00).

End of yesterday is start of today + seconds in a day.

I am assuming you work with milliseconds, but this can be adjusted.
Also everything is calculated in UTC.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz

today = datetime.utcnow().date() - timedelta(1)
start = int(datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, tzinfo=tz.tzutc()).timestamp()) * 1000 # milliseconds
end = start + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

str(start), str(end)
```

Output:

```
('1689033600000', '1689120000000')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It is what I have been looking for., but I now have a problem incorporating it in the query that I. have. Read the documentation and still struggle. My query looks like this:

Comment: today = datetime.utcnow().date() - timedelta(1)
start = int(datetime(today.year, today.month, today.day, tzinfo=tz.tzutc()).timestamp()) * 1000 # milliseconds
end = start + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

doc_query = query(doc_ref, and( where ('created', '>=' ,'start'), where ('created', '<=' ,'start')))

docs_all.stream()

for doc in docs_all:
    print(doc.to_dict())

Comment: this does not look good. will post in thread